# Получить текст из блока

Tags: jquery, регулярные-выражения

Есть блок из которого нужно вытащить текст, код блока выглядит так:

```
<div class="block">
    ...
    <hr>
    Нужный текст
    <div id="snewmes" align="right">...</div>
</div>
```

Нужный текст может быть любым, но он всегда между `<hr>` и `<div id="snewmes" align="right">..</div>`.
Как можно вытащить **нужный текст** как переменную?

Comment: Приведите пример вашего кода, что конкретно у вас не получается?

Comment: Те умники, что жмут на закрытие вопроса, пойдите лесом. Это не учебный вопрос.

Comment: @Anamnian, вопрос чутка не так сформалировал.. **Нужный текст** может быть любым текстом. Вытащить его нужно как переменную, хотя бы.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  var result, re, str;
  str=$('.block').text();
  re=new RegExp ("Нужный текст","i");
  result=str.match(re)
  alert(result)
});
```

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос.